# No Implicit Conversion Between UNIQUEIDENTIFIER and VARCHAR After Removing a Persisted Computed Column

Tags: sql-server

I have a couple of tables in a database where the primary key (stored as a  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) of one table is stored as a column in the other table as VARCHAR representation of the UNIQUEIDENTIFIER in the first table.

I added persisted computed column to the second table, so that it would store the VARCHAR value (if it was present) as a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER.

I did this by using the following formula for the persisted computed column:

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN isnull(ref_id, '') <> ''
            THEN cast(ref_id AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
        ELSE NULL
        END
```

It turns out that I don't need the persisted computed column, so I deleted it in SSMS.

The problem is that now when I want to join on the two columns, I get this error message:

> Conversion failed when converting from a character string to
>   uniqueidentifier.

This is a result of a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mngi_referral_ r
INNER JOIN mngi_ppa_ext_ ppa ON r.seq_no = ppa.ref_id
```

Previous to adding the computed column, I could join on these two columns (r.seq_no is a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER and ppa.ref_id is a VARCHAR). SQL Server simply did an implicit conversion and never complained.

I can still do this in other tables in the database without a problem. It seems to only be specific to this specific column ppa.ref_id) since I added and then subsequently deleted the computed persisted column.

Does anyone have any idea why this would be the case? I would greatly appreciate any insight you can offer.

Here is the table creation script for the table in question:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mngi_PPA_ext_](
    [enterprise_id] [char](5) NOT NULL,
    [practice_id] [char](4) NOT NULL,
    [person_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [created_by] [int] NOT NULL,
    [create_timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [create_timestamp_tz] [smallint] NULL,
    [modified_by] [int] NOT NULL,
    [modify_timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [modify_timestamp_tz] [smallint] NULL,
    [row_timestamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [seq_no] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [txt_proc] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [txt_date] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [txt_ref_status] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [txt_ref_source] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [txt_task_status] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [txt_mngi_loc] [varchar](75) NULL,
    [txt_mngi_provider] [varchar](75) NULL,
    [txt_new_update] [varchar](6) NULL,
    [txt_referral_md] [varchar](125) NULL,
    [txt_referral_link] [varchar](125) NULL,
    [txt_ref_md_firstname] [varchar](75) NULL,
    [txt_ref_md_lastname] [varchar](75) NULL,
    [txt_ref_md_provID] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [ref_id] [varchar](36) NULL,
    [txt_ref_phone] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [txt_interpreter] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [txt_diagnosis] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [txt_mngi_md_firstname] [varchar](75) NULL,
    [txt_mngi_md_lastname] [varchar](75) NULL,
    [txt_mngi_prov_id] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [chk_intrp] [int] NULL,
    [rbtn_sedation] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [txt_sedation_orderingMD] [varchar](125) NULL,
    [txt_ordering_MD_fname] [varchar](75) NULL,
    [txt_ordering_MD_lname] [varchar](75) NULL,
    [rbtn_lung] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [rbtn_allergicToAnes] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [txt_height_ft] [int] NULL,
    [txt_height_in] [int] NULL,
    [txt_weight] [int] NULL,
    [txt_BMI] [decimal](16, 2) NULL,
    [txt_height] [int] NULL,
    [txt_temp_proc] [varchar](55) NULL,
    [chk_send_task] [int] NULL,
    [pt_sx] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [rbtn_sendtask] [varchar](1) NULL,
    [mngi_ppa] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [chk_hide] [int] NULL,
    [contactDetailID] [varchar](36) NULL,
    [txt_procNameFull] [varchar](150) NULL,
    [txt_proc_assess_needed] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [txt_proc_assess_status] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [txt_proc_prep] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [txt_proc_seq_no] [varchar](36) NULL,
    [txt_change_reason] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [rbtn_changeReason] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [chk_uploadContactDtl] [int] NULL,
    [appt_id] [varchar](36) NULL,
    [referring_clinic_id] [varchar](36) NULL,
    [health_system_id] [varchar](36) NULL,
    [ApplicationUserId] [varchar](36) NULL,
    [chk_prepUpdatedManually] [int] NULL,
    [ReferringComments] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [ReferringCommentsSummary] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [completedDate] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [completedTime] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [txt_appt_date] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [txt_appt_rendering] [varchar](100) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [pk_mngi_ppa_ext_] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [seq_no] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 95) ON [NEXTGEN_INDEX_1]
) ON [NEXTGEN_CORE]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mngi_PPA_ext_] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [create_timestamp]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mngi_PPA_ext_] ADD  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [modify_timestamp]
GO
```

I've tried recompiling the table with `sp_recompile` to no avail.

There are not only `NULL` values, but also blank values in the column, along with valid `VARCHAR` representations of GUIDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blank values in the `ref_id` column will result in the query returning your error message.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.a;
CREATE TABLE dbo.a 
(
    i uniqueidentifier null
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.b;
CREATE TABLE dbo.b
(
    i varchar(36) null
);

INSERT INTO dbo.a (i)
VALUES (NEWID());

INSERT INTO dbo.b (i)
VALUES ('');

SELECT *
FROM dbo.a 
    INNER JOIN dbo.b ON a.i = b.i;
```

Results:

> Msg 8169, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
>   Conversion failed when converting from a character string to uniqueidentifier.

This serves as a pretty good example of why it is important to choose the correct data type for *each and every column*.  `uniqueidentifier` columns don't accept zero-length-strings in the first place.  You *can* insert NULL values, if you really need to.

This is the query plan, shown in [Sentry One's Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer) for the above sample query:

[image]

At the bottom of the image is a nice red warning about cardinality estimates being unreliable because of the implicit conversion required by joining a varchar(36) column to a uniqueidentifier column.  Any time you see this warning in a plan, fix the issue before it gets out of hand.  Great cardinality estimates are absolutely required for good performance.  Without them, SQL Server has almost no hope of creating a great query plan.

Comment: @BillKron Just to be sure you're aware, [a computed column can be indexed without being persisted](https://sqlperformance.com/2017/05/sql-plan/properly-persisted-computed-columns). Very common misconception that they're tied together.